# "Error: Unknown provider" trying to implement dependency injection in Angular.JS

Tags: angularjs

I'm brand new in Angular.JS and I'm trying to make a dependency injection but I got this:

```
// Definition
app.factory('Reload', function (load, $timeout, timeout) {
    if (!timeout) {
        timeout = 15 * 1000; // reload page every quater minute by default
    }
    return $timeout(load, timeout);
});


// Controller
app.controller('SomeController', function ($scope, $routeParams, $location, $timeout, Installer, Reload) {
  Reload(load, $timeout, 1000);
});

Error: Unknown provider: loadProvider <- load <- Reload
    at Error (<anonymous>)
    at http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.7/angular.js:2734:15
    at Object.getService [as get] (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.7/angular.js:2862:39)
    at http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.7/angular.js:2739:45
    at getService (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.7/angular.js:2862:39)
    at Object.invoke (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.7/angular.js:2880:13)
    at http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.7/angular.js:2740:37
    at getService (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.7/angular.js:2862:39)
    at invoke (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.7/angular.js:2880:13)
    at Object.instantiate (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.7/angular.js:2914:23)
```

What am I missing?. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The definition of the `Reload` factory gets mixed up between the factory definition and the function it returns.  Update your code as follows.

```
// Definition
app.factory('Reload', function ($timeout) {
    return function(load, timeout) {
        if (!timeout) {
            timeout = 15 * 1000; // reload page every quater minute by default
        }
        return $timeout(load, timeout);
    }
});


// Controller
app.controller('SomeController', function ($scope, $routeParams, $location, $timeout, Installer, Reload) {
  Reload(load, 1000);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You're passing a `load` provider into your `Reload`, that means a service `load` needs to be declared in the app.

if I understand you correctly i think you need to add

```
app.factory('load', function(){
  document.reload();
});
```

before your `Reload` declaration, if you're doing all that in the same file that is.

Having said that, unless you need a particularly complex reloading I would simply take out `load` from the injection and include it in the `$timeout` like

`return $timeout(document.reload, timeout);`

Comment: You're right, but I missied mention that "load" is a function that is inside the controller and I prefer to not putting it as a service

Answer (score 1):

I solved changing the code to:

```
// Factory definition
app.factory('Reload', function ($timeout) {
    return function (fnLoad, timeout) {
        if (!timeout) {
            timeout = 15 * 1000; // reload page every quater minute by default
        }
        return $timeout(fnLoad, timeout);
    };
});

// Controller
app.controller('InstallersController', function ($scope, $routeParams, $location, $timeout, Installer, Reload) {
  Reload(load);
}
```

Thanks to a co-worker...